# Weak* topology and product topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Q1 For any Hilbert space $H$ which has a countable orthonormal basis, could I say that $H^* \subset ∏_{a \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{C}_a$? I mean $H^*$ is a subspace of product topology?
($\mathbb{N}$ is positive integers and $\mathbb{C}_a$ is a complex number)

Q2 If I define $X=\{\{x_a \}\in  ∏_{a \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{C}_a : sup_a |x|< \inf \}$
Then is $X=H^*$?

The reason why I think this way is that if we look at the basis if we know all values for the basis we could define one linear map  $H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. So we only need to know countable data to define some linear map. For continuity(or boundness) we could conclude for every normal element in $H$ to some finite values as uniformly. So I think  $X=H^*$ could be true. In topologically and set theoretically. Am I right?

Comment: I am presuming your product space is just $\mathbb{C}^\infty:=\prod_{n\ge 1}\mathbb{C}$—i.e., the Cartesian product of countable copies $\mathbb{C}$, or? In any case, the elements of the dual Hilbert space (by the linear isomorphism $\ell^2=(\ell^2)^*$) can indeed be identified as a elements of this product space——of course, $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}\in H^*$ implies $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}\in\mathbb{C}^\infty$——but if you’re enquiring whether the norm topology on $H^*$ is the same as that obtained from the product topology on $\mathbb{C}^\infty$, then the answer is no.

Comment: Yes, my product space is what you said. Thanks for your answer. I have one(two?) more question which is related to that $H^*$ and $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ has different topology. If we define ball in $H^*$ as ${B^*}(0,r)$ and define ball in $\mathbb{C}$ as $B(0,r)$ then ${B^*}(0,r)$= $∏B(0,r)$? Then could I say  $H^*$ is subspace topology of $\mathbb{C}^\infty$?

Comment: No, the unit ball in your Hilbert space is not the same as the product of complex unit balls. (You can see the reason by considering $\mathbb{R}^2$, whose unit ball is the interior of the unit circle, whereas the product of the unit balls in $\mathbb{R}$ is the interior of the unit square—in the unitary space $\mathbb{C}^n$, such products are called polydiscs, and **in that case** the product topology (which becomes the box topology) agrees with the norm topology on the unit ball, though geometrically, the polydisc and unit balls are the same: one is cuboid, the other is round!....

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. Right now I am not sure I understand it 100%. I think I should take some time to organize things. But I could catch some ideas. Thanks for your help.

Comment: .... however, the norm topology of the unit ball in the Hilbert space does not agree with the product topology of $\prod B(0,1)$. In the latter, the open sets will have to contain all, but a finite number of, the unit balls making up $\prod B(0,1)$. So for instance the open ball $B^*(0,\epsilon)$ of radius $\epsilon<1$ in $H^*$ centered at $0$ is not open in $\prod B(0,1)$ because $B^*(0,\epsilon)\subset\prod B(0,\epsilon)$ so $B^*(0,\epsilon)$ cannot contain an infinite copy of the unit balls making up $\prod B(0,1)$.

Comment: (In my earlier answer, I meant to say that _geometrically the polydisc and unit ball are **not** the same_.))